API change in C - 1D array to 2D array
I am a little confused on how to do this API change.
Given an init() function that receives struct params *params, inside this struct is another struct x **ptr.
The user fills out an array of struct x *arr[MAX_NUM], and simply does params->ptr = arr.
The API change that I want to do is extend this array to be 2D array of pointers, so essentially it turns to struct x *arr[MAX_NUM][MAX_NUM] (a 2D array of pointers to struct x). The idea is to be able to traverse this 2D array in init() using row and column. How can I do that properly with a pointer to a 2D array?
Changing struct x **ptr to struct *x[MAX][MAX] obviously doesn't work as you cannot assign arrays like that with '='. I thought about something like struct x *(*ptr)[MAX_NUM] but that is merely a pointer to a 1D array of pointers. I also thought about struct x *(*ptr)[MAX_NUM][MAX_NUM] but that becomes an issue later in the code because every member is now a pointer to a pointer rather than a pointer and I do not want to change the entire codebase to become double pointers rather than one, or access that specifically with *. Is there anything easier and better that I'm missing?

You can have a struct x *(*ptr)[MAX_NUM] that points to the first row of a struct x *array[SOME_NUM][MAX_NUM]. In other words, the assignment ptr = array; is a type-compatible assignment.

You should probably look at simplifying this code rather than making it more complex. I started to sketch on a solution with a union, but it turned so obscure that I can't recommend it. If you allow your user to assign arrays of pointers to struct members, then that's not a very good design - they shouldn't be meddling with stuff like that directly and the big potential for bugs is there even without the modifications you want. Possibly this should all be redesigned to use an opaque type with a proper API.
